# How to select distinct on with different order by Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hello i want to query a table and make a select distinct on but with different ordey by and i want this with desc.
How can i do this?

```
CREATE TABLE test_dupl2(id SERIAL, letter_one TEXT, number_int INT, primary key (id));

INSERT INTO test_dupl2(letter_one,number_int) VALUES ('A',1), ('A',2), ('B',1), ('A', 9), ('B', 4);
```

My query

```
select letter_one, number_int from
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (letter_one) letter_one, number_int FROM test_dupl2) as foo
order by foo.number_int desc;
```

The wrong output:

```
('A', 1), ('B', 1)
```

The output i want:

```
('A', 9), ('B', 4)
```

Postgresql9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct on (letter_one) letter_one, number_int 
from test_dupl2
order by 1, 2 desc;

 letter_one | number_int 
------------+------------
 A          |          9
 B          |          4
(2 rows)
```

Comment: can you explain me this part "order by 1, 2" desc @klin ?

Comment: Order by first and second column, abbrev. for `order by letter_one, number_int desc`.